# If F is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3} \in F$ then both $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ in F?

Tags: field-theory

I'm trying to show that $\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3} \in$ F given that F is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3} \in F$.

Here is my work so far

$$\sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3} \in F$$ 
$$(\sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3})^2 = (5+ 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt3) \in F \Longrightarrow \sqrt{2}\sqrt3 \in F$$

After this part I'm not sure what to do. I feel like both the sum and the product of $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{3}$ being in the field should imply that the individual elements are in the field but I'm not if this is correct or how to justify it. I was wondering whether someone can tell me if I'm on the right track or not and give a hint as to how the proof goes.

==================================================================
Would this work

$$\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}(\sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3}) = 2\sqrt{3}+3\sqrt{2} \in F$$
$$2\sqrt{3}+3\sqrt{2} -2(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}) =\sqrt{2}\in F $$
Since $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{6}$ are in F then it follows that $\sqrt{3}$ is in F just by dividing by $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: "I feel like both the sum and the product of $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{3}$ being in the field should imply that the individual elements are in the field" In general, it doesn't. If $a+b$ and $ab$ are both in a field, what that means exactly is that $a$ and $b$ are the roots of the polynomial $x^2-(a+b)x+ab$, and may very well fail to be in the field.

Comment: @Arthur I believe you but could I get a concrete example of a field where it fails?

Comment: The golden ratio $\phi\approx1.618$, the negative of the inverse of the golden ratio $-\frac1\phi$, and $F=\Bbb Q$. Their product is $-1$ and their sum is $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $F$ is a field and  $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3} \in F$, its inverse is also in $F$. That is ,

$$(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^{-1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}.\frac{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}}=-1(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}) \in F $$

Hence $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+(-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})=2 \sqrt{3} \in F$ and so $\sqrt{3} \in F$

Similarly $\sqrt{2} \in F$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Consider $(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)^3$ instead.

Comment: Any reasoning behind why we should consider the expression cubed?

Comment: @user262291 Try it and see. What do you get?

Comment: $11\sqrt{2} + 9\sqrt{3}$. Is the idea that then you can subtract $9(\sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3})$ to end up with $2\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @user262291 And then you're done! (Remember that $\frac12\in F$ too)

Comment: @user262291 (The reason you should try it cubed instead of squared is that this way, when expanding, an odd power of $\sqrt2$ is always multiplied by an even power of $\sqrt3$ and vice versa, meaning you won't get any $\sqrt6$ terms.)